# react-native project/directory structure setup

Tags: structure, react-native

I'm learning react-native(android) on windows environment. I've manage to start a project on android(even though they only support for apple). I want some advice for naming good structures of files and folders for the project before I go deep into the code/learning. I want to organize things beforehand. Can anyone help me?

Ex. for html something like

```
www
 |-js
 |-css
 |-img
build
 |-js
 |-css
 |-less
...
```

react-native init structures have something like

```
android
node_modules
package.json
index.android.js
...
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I recommend using Flux or something similar and then putting the actions/stores/dispatcher/etc in their own folders. This is my app structure:
[image: React Native app structure]

Answer (score 18):

I think questioner had already resolved the issue. But I'm writing for the newcomers to React Native.

As specified on the [official React Native site](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#content) , we don't need to concern file/directory structure for different platform as IOS and Android.

> For example, you can have these files in your project:
>
> `BigButton.ios.js` 
>   `BigButton.android.js`

So, we can construct and organize our files according to the our awesome app's logic. For instance; We can create a folder with name `screens` or `views` folder. Then we can put our login screen `login.ios.js`, `login.android.js` and `lock.png` (and maybe there will be another [lock@2x.png](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#content) file) files into a folder that is named as `login` which would be created in our `screens` folder. (I seperated login js files for the sake of example).

As a result out directory organization like be the following;

```
AwesomeProject\android\..
AwesomeProject\ios\..
AwesomeProject\screens\login\login.android.js
AwesomeProject\screens\login\login.ios.js
AwesomeProject\screens\login\lock.png
```

In fact, the end of our organization `screens` (or views) folder is been very similar to View part of MVC structure like in a web application.

I hope this helps.

PS: I don't know what is Flux which has been mentioned by @eyal83 . It may be better solution.

### Edited

---

I've searched some application architecture libraries. 
According to my search, in developing complex applications, using Flux or one of its derivatives would be beneficial.

So, @eyal83 is right.(I've incremented his answer +1)

**Flux sites**: [Github](https://github.com/facebook/flux) - [Homepage](http://facebook.github.io/flux/)

Some popular **Flux derivatives/suchlike** frameworks;

**Redux.....:** [Github](http://github.com/reactjs/redux) - [Homepage](http://redux.js.org/) - [A Free Course by Its Creator](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux)

**MobX.........:** [Github](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) - [Homepage](https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/)

**Reflux.....:** [Github](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs)

**Alt...........:** [Github](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt) - [Homepage](http://alt.js.org/)

**Flummox:** [Github](https://github.com/acdlite/flummox) - [Homepage](http://acdlite.github.io/flummox)

**Yahoo / Fluxible:** [Github](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible) - [Homepage](http://fluxible.io/)

**Nuclear-js..........:** [Github](https://github.com/optimizely/nuclear-js) - [Homepage](https://optimizely.github.io/nuclear-js/)

Recently, I've been trying to learn one of them too.